# Solving equation with LambertW function?

Tags: special-functions, closed-form

Does the equation

$$
a = b x e^x + c x + d e^x
$$

have a solution form solution?

I tried to look for it by using the LambertW funcion, but I did not succeed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you mean "closed form solution".  No, I don't think it does.  Maple doesn't think so either.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Not unless $c=0$.

Comment: ... or $b = 0$, or $a=-cd/b$, or various other special cases.

Comment: You could not get any closed form solution. If you need to solve it for specific values of $a,b,c,d$, just post them and I shall show you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers.

The relation that I have is b=cd and a=cd-1.

I do not think there is a close form solution; Please let me know if there was.

Comment: This does not help, unfortunately ! I suppose that you will need to go to numerical methods. If you want, we can try if you provide values for your parameters.

Comment: Thanks a lot Claude.
I wanted a closed form solution because it comes from an optimization problem. I will solve it with numerical methods.